# Are there any libraries/API's available for converting SVG fonts into TTF (or other formats)?

Tags: java, php, ruby, fonts, web

I have an idea for a web application and part of it involves the user uploading an SVG font and the app converting it to TTF and eventually other formats.

Are there libraries that can do this? I've found some that convert from TTF to SVG, like Batik, but I'd like to do it the other way around.

I'm open to any language: PHP, Ruby, Java, etc. just really at this point trying to see if this is possible.

Comment: Not pretty sure. But this is a java based application that does just you need.. You can extend this in your app http://www.udel.edu/CIS/software/dist/batik-1.6/docs/ttf2svg.html